# reset root password for some of mysql instance

Tags: mysql, passwords, root, reset, instances

I searched a lot in the net, but the results I found is how to reset MySQL root password. But I want to know how to reset MySQL root password for some of my other MySQL instances...

Below are details:

OS: **Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS**

MySQL: **5.5.40**

I have 5 instances of mysql, I know how to reset the root password of the main MySQL installation, but I do not know how to do it for some of the others MySQL instances.

Here is how I'm trying to login:
**mysql --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld3.sock -u UserName -p**
whatever user or pass I'm typing it shows me access denied for UserName.... etc...

This is my first question here, so excuse me if something is not explained clear enough

Comment: Check this link may help you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: It's explained pretty well, but it's explained about the main MySQL installation, not if I have more instances. So when I reach the step to start running the server like that:
mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
it's for the main MySQL installation, not for some of my another instances

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used `mysqld_safe --mysqld=/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/home/test/data/mysql --datadir=/home/test/data --skip-grant-tables`. The point is to provide data and/or instalation dirs (don't know if both are needed). I also had to tell where mysqld was but this might be specific to my case only. After starting the instance I wanted reset root password to I did all the actions needed to make it happen, killed all mysqld processes and repeated everything for another MySQL instance.